# Include not mapped variable

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have two tables `User` and `Visits` - which contains user ID and all his visits on site.
This is what I have done so far. Is it possible to `Count` user's visits using EF without foreach loop?

```
List<User> users = repo.Include(x => x.History).ToList();
foreach(User u in users)
{
    u.NumOfVisits = u.History.Count();
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set;}
    [NotMapped]
    public int NumOfVisits { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public IEnumerable<Visit> History { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var users = repo.Include(x => x.History)
                .Select(x => new { User = x, HistoryCount = x.History.Count() })
                .ToList();
```

`users` will be a list of anonymous type objects with just two properties: `User` and `HistoryCount`.